# Configure rspec to exclude a folder unless it is explicitly given to rspec to run

Tags: rspec, configuration, rspec3

I want to exclude a folder from rspec tests unless it is explicitly given as a command line argument to run. For example

```
RSpec.configure do |config|

  unless rspec_args.any? { |arg| =~ /shared/ } # do not explicitly run shared folder
    config.exclude_pattern = 'shared/**/*_spec.rb' 
  end

end
```

I am using rspec v3.9

I have two problems:

1. Configuring `exlude_pattern` with `config.exclude_pattern = 'shared/**/*_spec.rb'` doesn't seem to exclude shared folder from tests to run. But when I run `rspec --exclude-pattern shared/**/*_spec.rb` shared folder gets excluded from the test suite
2. How to get arguments passed to rspec from command line in the code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was able to achieve this with the following configuration:

```
# .rspec
--require spec_helper
```

---

```
# spec_helper.rb
RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.exclude_pattern = 'shared/**/*_spec.rb' 
end
```

Answer (score 0):

[The accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59158280/6045800) doesn't answer the concern that we want to be able to run the excluded directory explicitly.

Here's my solution that works:

```
config.exclude_pattern = 'spec/v1/**/*_spec.rb' unless ARGV.detect { _1 =~ /^spec/ } =~ /^spec\/v1/
```